# Regular expression to find words starting with no number

Tags: regex, python-re

I need to match a string with an *identifier*.

#### Pattern

Any word will be considered as *identifier* if

1. Word doesn't contain any character rather than alpha-numeric characters.
2. Word doesn't start with number.

#### Input

The given input string will not contain any preceding or trailing spaces or white-space characters.

#### Code

I tried using the following regular expressions

1. `\D[a-zA-Z]\w*\D`
2. `[ \t\n][a-zA-Z]\w*[ \t\n]`
3. `^\D[a-zA-Z]\w*$`

None of them works.

How can I achieve this?

Note I want to match a string that contains multiple identifiers (also can be one). For example `This is an i0dentifier 1abs`, where `i0dentifier`, `This`, `is`, `an` are expected results.

Comment: Have you tried `^[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]*`?

Comment: Will the string only contain a single identifier or not match at all. So that any given input string that matches, consists completely of a single identifier without any noise ? Can you give example inputs and the expected result.

Comment: @hc_dev` the string will contain more than one identifier. like ```Hello this is an 1identifier x ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in your `^\D[a-zA-Z]\w*$` regex, `\D` can match non-alphanumeric chars since `\D` matches any non-digit chars, and `\w` also matches underscores, which is not an alphanumeric char.

I suggest

```
\b[A-Za-z]+[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*\b
```

It matches

- `\b` - word boundary
- `[A-Za-z]+` - one or more letters (the identifier should start with a letter)
- `[0-9]` - a digit (required)
- `[A-Za-z0-9]*` - zero or more ASCII letters/digits
- `\b` - word boundary.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/beBsd5/5).

In Python:

```py
identifiers = re.findall(r'\b[A-Za-z]+[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*\b', text)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of _negative look-ahead_ ? Does [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74956299/5730279) simplify to much when just excluding any input with digit at first position?

Comment: @hc_dev *no digit allowed immediately to the right of the current location*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this regular expression works with strings contains only one identifier. But I want to match a string contains multiple identifiers (also can be one). For example ```This is an i0dentifier 1abs```

Comment: @RidwanFaiz Not a problem, your requirements seem to be different from what you ask in the question, but I changed the solution to accommodate for it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it worked. But I needed to do a simple tweak to fulfill my need.```\b[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*\b```

Comment: @RidwanFaiz Well, I thought `This` is not an identifier, but anyway, glad it finally worked out.

Answer (score 1):

A `\D` matches any non-digit characters including not only alphabets but also punctuation characters, whitespace characters etc. and you definitely do not need them in the beginning.

You can use `^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$` which can be described as

- `^`: Start of string
- `[A-Za-z]`: An alphabet
- `[A-Za-z0-9]*`: An alphanumeric character, zero or more times
- `$`: End of string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9w1KTd/1)

Answer (score 1):

An even simpler pattern for *identifier* - not using [*negative lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) like [Wiktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74954775/5730279):

`^[^0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*$` decomposed and explained:

1. `^[^0-9]`: Word starts `^` not `[^` with a number `0-9]` (more exactly, first char is not a digit, but second character can be a digit!).
2. `[A-Za-z0-9]*`:  Word doesn't contain any character rather than alpha-numeric characters (not even hyphen or underscore) until the end `$`.

See [demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZjfWF0/1).

#### Positive alternative

As [already suggested by Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74955481/5730279):
If (according to both rules) the first char must not be a digit or numeric, but only an alpha, then we could also exchange the first part from above regex from "not-numeric" to "only-alpha".

`[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*` explained:

1. `[A-Za-z]`: first char must be an alpha
2. `[A-Za-z0-9]*`: optional second and following chars can be any alpha-numeric

Same effect, see [demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BtPs7i/1).

#### Tests

| input | result | reason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aB123 | matches identifier |  |
| Ab123 | matches identifier |  |
| XXXX12YZ | matches identifier |  |
| a2b3 | matches identifier |  |
| a | matches identifier |  |
| Z | matches identifier |  |
| 0 | no match | starts with a digit |
| 1Ab | no match | starts with a digit |
| 12abc | no match | starts with a digit |
| abc_123 | no match | contains underscore, not alphanum |
| r2-d2 | no match | contains hyphen, not alphanum |

Comment: I guess the `[^0-9]` would match anything besides a digit which could even be any non-word character ([example](https://regex101.com/r/RTHi1T/1)). Though the whole question reads not very clear to me. :)